# Unable to create CKAN extension using ckan generate extension and cookiecutter - any solutions?

Tags: ckan

I'm having problems to create an extension in CKAN

I have to customize the theme of a CKAN installation (footer, header, etc.).

According to the CKAN documentation, I have to create an extension first, but I can't do it in any of the ways, neither with the ckan generate extension command nor with cookiecutter.

If I put the command `ckan generate extension`, I get this error:

[image: error when I try to generate an extension con ckan generate extension command]

I have cookie cutter installed and I have already installed the dependencies specified in the requirements files, as indicated in the documentation:

```
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ckan/ckan/ckan-2.10.0/requirements.txt
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ckan/ckan/ckan-2.10.0/dev-requirements.txt
```

If I try to create the extension with cookiecutter following these commands:

```
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src
cookiecutter ckan/contrib/cookiecutter/ckan_extension/
```

After putting all the data requested in the cli, I get this error:

[image: error after try to create a plugin with cookiecutter]